# Where should I apply dropout to a convolutional layer?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Because the word "layer" often means different things when applied to a convolutional layer (some treat everything up through pooling as a single layer, others treat convolution, nonlinearity, and pooling as separate "layers"; [see fig 9.7](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html)) it's not clear to me where to apply dropout in a convolutional layer.

Does dropout happen between nonlinearity and pooling?

---

E.g., in TensorFlow would it be something like:

```
kernel_logits = tf.nn.conv2d(input_tensor, ...) + biases
activations = tf.nn.relu(kernel_logits)
kept_activations = tf.nn.dropout(activations, keep_prob)
output = pool_fn(kept_activations, ...)
```

Comment: [Another example](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/#dropout) suggests applying dropout after pooling.

Comment: I've been doing experiments with using dropout instead of average downsampling over a 2x2 area for images.  My theory was that instead of downsampling each 2x2 image area, if instead dropout was used to effectively make many more slightly different images then I'd effectively have more training samples and be able to train long and get better results.  After trying many different setups and long training runs, dropout as a means to turn downsampling into content generation has proven ineffective.

Comment: Update, using 3x3 actually makes a huge difference.  Using dropout over a 3x3 downsample instead of just doing an average for a 3x3 downsample makes a significant difference.  On MNIST, this translates to a 92.5% correct using dropout on 3x3 downsample to conv then maxpool vs 84.2% correct using average on 3x3 downsample to conv then maxpool.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably try applying dropout at different places, but in terms of preventing overfitting not sure you're going to see much of a problem before pooling. What I've seen for CNN is that `tensorflow.nn.dropout` gets applied AFTER non-linearity and pooling:

```
    # Create a convolution + maxpool layer for each filter size
    pooled_outputs = []
    for i, filter_size in enumerate(filters):
        with tf.name_scope("conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
            # Convolution Layer
            filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                self.embedded_chars_expanded,
                W,
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="conv")
            # Apply nonlinearity
            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")
            # Maxpooling over the outputs
            pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, sequence_length - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID',
                name="pool")
            pooled_outputs.append(pooled)



    # Combine all the pooled features
    num_filters_total = num_filters * len(filters)
    self.h_pool = tf.concat(3, pooled_outputs)
    self.h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(self.h_pool, [-1, num_filters_total])

    # Add dropout
    with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
        self.h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat, self.dropout_keep_prob)
```

Comment: Re: "in terms of preventing overfitting not sure you're going to see much of a problem before pooling": I don't think its to avoid overfitting at the convolutional layer; it's to [introduce noise into later layers](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) (last paragraph before section 6.1.3).